# Split the string at the word before the next colon?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to split this string between the first colon entry and the next word that includes a colon. The string is a long text. It can have a period or comma between the colons.

For example, if I have the following string.

```
String s       = "Description: This is the description. Observation: This is the description.";
String[] parts = s.split("REGULAR_EXPRESSION");
```

The result would be:

```
This is the description.
```

For example if the string is

```
"Description: This is. The, description. Words: words words"
```

The result would be:

```
This is. The, description.
```

Comment: So you actually want to capture things after the colon ":", but before the next sentence, yes?

Comment: If you split where you asked, you would get `Description: This is the description.`. Why then do you expect `This is the description`

Comment: Yes. The word "Description:" is always there. But the word before the next ":" can be any word. Between "Description:" and this word is the string I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want what you ask, you need a regex that splits by colon and period.

Something like this?

```
:.+\.
```

EDIT: Here is a breakdown of this regular expression (as requested by Roman C)

`:` matches the colon character (`:`) literally

`.+` matches any character one and unlimited times, greedy (except newline)

`\.` matches the period character (`.`) literally

Comment: While this something looks like regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This splits the string on *both* the colon or period. Element index 1 (the second element) is what you want. Just trim it.

```
String description = "Description: This is the description. Observation: This is the description.".
   split("[\\.:]")[1].trim();
```

You could also pre-trim it:

```
String description = "Description: This is the description. Observation: This is the description.".
   split("[\\.:] +")[1];
```

Use `"[\\.:]\\s+"` if there might be non-space whitespace.

Comment: I does not work for me because the string "This is the description" can have "." ... For example if the string is "Description: This is. the. description. Words: words words". The output is "This is" not "This is. the. description."

Comment: That information was not in your question, so of course I could not know about it.

Comment: I know that. That's why I said "I does not work *for me*". I didn't said it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Split is not the best method to use. This code gets you the part you want:

```
String part = string.replaceAll("\\w+:\\s+(.*?)\\s+\\w+:.*", "$1");
```

This also trims the part extracted.

---

Some test code:

```
String string = "Description: This is the description. Observation: This is the description.";
String part = string.replaceAll("\\w+:\\s+(.*?)\\s+\\w+:.*", "$1");
System.out.println(part);
```

Output:

```
This is the description.
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the next?:

```
String string = "Description: This is the description. Observation: This is the description.";
String str = string.replaceFirst(".*:\\s+(.*)", "$1");
```